# Can't index .odt files with Recoll under Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, python, libreoffice, pip, recoll

Recoll can't index Open Document files.

When reviewing settings in Recoll, I get next list of missing helpers:

```
External applications/commands needed for your file types and not found, as stored by the last indexing pass in /home/pf/.recoll/missing:
  python:chm (application/x-chm)
  python:libxml2/python:libxslt1 (application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-flat-xml application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document application/vnd.sun.xml.writer image/svg+xml)
  python:midi (audio/x-karaoke)
```

I don't care about midi files and x-chm stuff, but I would really like the Open Document files to be indexed.

I installed next packages with **apt**:

```
libxml2-dev 
libxslt1-dev
python-lxml
```

I also installed next package with **pip**:

```
lxml
```

I found no more ideas to solve my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found in https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/pages/features.html#doctypes that recoll versions >= 1.26 do not need helpers for Open Office files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 20.04 --

I found in [lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/pages/features.html#doctypes that recoll](https://lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/pages/features.html#doctypes) versions >= 1.26 do not need helpers for Open Office files. This seemed to be correct. I installed `recoll` on a test 20.04 system and it asked for only the helper `antiword`. I installed that. After starting an index from scratch, it sucessfully found words in an .odt file

[image]

For 18.04 --

The package you install to get `recoll` to index the OpenOffice files is

`python-libxslt1`

Reference [here](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/bitbucket-issues-recoll/issue-322.html)

> I managed to fix non-indexing of ods files in debian by installing this dependency: apt-get install python-libxslt1

I also always install

```
python-mutagen
python-chm
ibimage-exiftool-perl
```

Comment: When I issue `sudo apt-get install python-libxslt1` on Ubuntu 20.04, I get an error: `Unable to locate package python-libxslt1`.

Comment: SInce the package `python-libxslt1` has been removed from Ubuntu 20.04, I installed the package from a previous version (18.04 LTS) after downloading it from URL `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxslt/python-libxslt1_1.1.29-5ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb`. **Recoll** still complains about the missing helper.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that it has been removed from 20.04! I hope this gets resolved, eventually I will have to move on from 18.04 and this is important functionality for us.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the hints I received.

I tried to rebuild the index but got an error. I removed the `$HOME/.recoll` directory to rebuild the index from scratch and the message about some missing helpers disappeared.

What hapenned? I guess the indexes of Recoll could have got messed during the upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

Finally, the problem seems to be solved after rebuilding the indexes from scratch.

By the way, other missing helpers have appeared:

```
python3:mutagen (application/ogg audio/mpeg video/mp4)
python3:rarfile/python3:unrar (application/x-rar)
unrtf (text/rtf)
wpd2html (application/vnd.wordperfect)
```

but I hope to solve this new issue with the information provided by Organic Marble at https://lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/pages/features.html